# Cannot modify data of type com.google.hydration

Tags: google-api, google-fit, google-apis-explorer, google-fit-api

I need to synchronize the amount of water drank, after reading the documentation, I'm trying to make a request to create a new Data Source:

```
POST /fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 342
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer -....-
{
  "dataStreamName": "HydrationSource",
  "type": "raw",
  "application": {
    "detailsUrl": "http://example.com",
    "name": "My Example App",
    "version": "1"
  },
  "dataType": {
    "name": "com.google.hydration",
    "field": [
     {
      "name": "volume",
      "format": "floatPoint",
      "optional": false
     }
    ]
   }
}
```

but I get "Cannot modify data of type com.google.hydration"

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-length: 305
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 12:23:22 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "error": {
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
    "message": "Cannot modify data of type com.google.hydration", 
    "code": 403, 
    "errors": [
      {
        "reason": "forbidden", 
        "message": "Cannot modify data of type com.google.hydration", 
        "domain": "global"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm experimenting in [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

fitness.nutrition.write is enabled:

[image]

I'm checking the examples from [docs](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/add-hydration-data?hl=ru), so the example with **com.google.nutrition** works:

```
POST /fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 229
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer -....-
{
  "dataStreamName": "NutritionSource",
  "type": "raw",
  "application": {
    "detailsUrl": "http://example.com",
    "name": "My Example App",
    "version": "1"
  },
  "dataType": {
    "name": "com.google.nutrition",
   }
}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 622
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 12:21:36 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "dataQualityStandard": [], 
  "dataType": {
    "field": [
      {
        "name": "nutrients", 
        "format": "map"
      }, 
      {
        "optional": true, 
        "name": "meal_type", 
        "format": "integer"
      }, 
      {
        "optional": true, 
        "name": "food_item", 
        "format": "string"
      }
    ], 
    "name": "com.google.nutrition"
  }, 
  "dataStreamName": "NutritionSource", 
  "application": {
    "version": "1", 
    "name": "My Example App", 
    "detailsUrl": "http://example.com"
  }, 
  "dataStreamId": "raw:com.google.nutrition:407408718192:NutritionSource", 
  "type": "raw"
}
```

But **com.google.hydration** doesn't work, even though they are from the same permission

Comment: There was an issue here, but it should now be fixed. Could you try again and let me know if it is working for you?

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried through OAuth 2.0 Playground and it's works, thank you!

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to specify the fields when you create the data source, if it is a Google-provided type: just the type name is required.